# Unification and Gaussian Elimination

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic

Does anyone knows of references that precisely spell out the connection between the [unification algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29) and Gaussian elimination? I'm particularly interested in the relationship between [triangular substitutions](http://www.nicta.com.au/pub?doc=3724) and LU decompositions.

Wayne Snyder and Jean Gallier mention this analogy in passing in their paper, [*Higher-Order Unification Revisited: Complete Sets of Transformations*](http://cifo.in/uploads/Higher%20order%20unification%20revisited.pdf).

Comment: As a non-expert, I had never heard of the connection.  Some reference which mentions this connection would be a nice addition to the question.

Comment: as they state in the paper p2, its mostly an analogy, "which in the higher order case breaks down". there is a demonstrable connection or analogy between resolution & gaussian elimination. close enough?

Comment: I expect that you already know this: Euclid's algorithm, Gaussian elimination, Buchberger's algorithm for Grobner bases and Knuth-Bendix completion are supposed to form a strictly increasing sequence in terms of generality and method they use. If the precise maps between these methods is known, maybe you could derive the connection above?

Comment: @VijayD: I didn't know that, actually! I know what Buchberger's algorithm does, but I don't know the algorithm itself, or anything at all about its relationship to Guassian elimination or KB completion.

Answer (score 13):

I don't consider this an answer. I'm abusing the answer box to pretty print a comment.

There is a strict sense in which Euclid's GCD algorithm, Gaussian elimination, Buchberger's algorithm and Knuth-Bendix form a strict sequence of generalisations and are all instances of what is called a *completion algorithm*. There is also a close relationship between these algorithms and resolution in logic. I do not know a good reference for this but I have seen the fact mentioned very often. These might help.

1. [History and basic features of the critical-pair/completion procedure](http://www.risc.jku.at/publications/download/risc_353/1987-04-00-A.pdf), Bruno Buchberger, 1987
2. [Canonical Reduction Systems in Symbolic Mathematics](http://www.risc.jku.at/education/courses/ss2011/rw/1-intro.pdf), Franz Winkler. [Springer Link](http://www.springerlink.com/content/w37631426j273383/)

Let me know if you find better references.